# I need help drawing an execution trace tree for this recursive methods

Tags: java, recursion

I am pretty new to JAVA. I want to draw the Execution Trace Tree for the two input strings “repaper” and “refinisher” for each of the two versions of the palindrome testing method

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String testCase1 = "repaper";
        String testCase2 = "refinisher";

        if ( isPalindrome_Version_1 ( testCase1 ) )
            System.out.println ( "The string \"" + testCase1 + "\" is a palindrome" );
        else
            System.out.println ( "The string \"" + testCase1 + "\" is NOT a palindrome" );
    }

    // return "true" iff the String s is a palindrome
    private static boolean isPalindrome_Version_1 ( String s )
    {
        boolean result = false;

        // BASE CASE
        if ( s.length() <= 1 )
            return (true);

        // BASE CASE - check if first char equals last char
        if ( s.charAt(0)  !=  s.charAt ( s.length() - 1 ) )
            return ( false );

        // GENERAL CASE - check whether the substring formed by removing 
        //                the first and last letters is a palindrome
        result = isPalindrome_Version_1 ( s.substring ( 1, s.length() - 1 ) );

        return( result );
    }

    // return "true" iff the String s is a palindrome
    private static boolean isPalindrome_Version_2 ( String s )
    {
        boolean result = false;

        // BASE CASE
        if ( s.length() <= 1 )
            return (true);

        // GENERAL CASE - check whether the substring formed by removing 
        //                the first and last letters is a palindrome
        result = isPalindrome_Version_2 ( s.substring ( 1, s.length() - 1 ) );

        // BASE CASE - check if first char equals last char
        if ( s.charAt(0)  !=  s.charAt ( s.length() - 1 ) )
            return ( false );

        return( result  );
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying to achieve, can you be more explicit. If you want to print every input string for your recursive method you should pass a level parameter to draw the input per level on the recursion

Comment: I need a total of 4 trace trees. Each node in the tree drawing indicating the value of the parameter that was passed to that method-call, and the value returned by that method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static boolean isPalindrome_Version_2 ( String s)
{
    boolean result = false;

    // BASE CASE
    if ( s.length() <= 1 ){
         System.out.println("Input Value :" + s + "Return Value" + true);
        return (true);

    // GENERAL CASE - check whether the substring formed by removing 
    //                the first and last letters is a palindrome
    result = isPalindrome_Version_2 ( s.substring ( 1, s.length() - 1 ) );

    // BASE CASE - check if first char equals last char
    if ( s.charAt(0)  !=  s.charAt ( s.length() - 1 ) )
   {
        System.out.println("Input Value :" + s + "Return Value" + false);
        return ( false );
   }

    System.out.println("Input Value :" + s + "Return Value" + result);
    return( result  );
}
```

Or something like this to know how deep is going your recursion

```
private static boolean isPalindrome_Version_2 ( String s, int level)
{
    boolean result = false;

    // BASE CASE
    if ( s.length() <= 1 ){
         System.out.println("Input Value :" + s + "Return Value" + true + "Recursion Level" + level);
        return (true);

    // GENERAL CASE - check whether the substring formed by removing 
    //                the first and last letters is a palindrome
    result = isPalindrome_Version_2 ( s.substring ( 1, s.length() - 1 ), level ++ );

    // BASE CASE - check if first char equals last char
    if ( s.charAt(0)  !=  s.charAt ( s.length() - 1 ) )
   {
        System.out.println("Input Value :" + s + "Return Value" + false+ "Recursion Level" + level);
        return ( false );
   }

    System.out.println("Input Value :" + s + "Return Value" + result+ "Recursion Level" + level);
    return( result  );
}
```

Btw here you have another solution for your recursion

```
    public static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
    {
        if(s == "") return true;

        return IsPalindrome(s, 0, s.length() - 1);
    }

    static bool IsPalindrome(string s, int start, int end)
    {
        if(s[start] == s[end])
        {
            if(start >= end) return true;

            else return IsPalindrome(s, start + 1, end - 1);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Version 2 is correct (or at least efficient) because you return false after recursing the whole string ...

That being said, here is the trace of Version 1

```
isPalindrome("repaper") // length greater than 1 and ending characters are equal
    isPalindrome("epape") // length greater than 1 and ending characters are equal
        isPalindrome("pap") // length greater than 1 and ending characters are equal
            isPalindrome("a") // length is 1, return true
```

Test case 2

```
isPalindrome("refinisher") // length greater than 1 and ending characters are equal
    isPalindrome("efinishe") // length greater than 1 and ending characters are equal
        isPalindrome("finish") // length greater than 1 but ending characters are not equal, return false
```

You should be able to do Version 2 on your own now